# Laravel ошибка сервера при переходе с главной страницы

Tags: php, laravel, apache2

Только начал осваивать laravel и столкнулся с такой ошибкой(При переходе с главной страницы на любую другую):

> You don't have permission to access
>   /media/sf_www/laravel-test/public/index.php on this server.

Настройка сервера - sites-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.laravel-test

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /media/sf_www/laravel-test
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Настройки сервера conf-available:

```
Alias /laravel-test /media/sf_www/laravel-test/public

<Directory /media/sf_www/laravel-test>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Фаил .htaccess в папке laravel-test/public

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: А почему просто не сделать документ рут `/media/sf_www/laravel-test/public`?

Answer (score 0):

У вас скорее всего проблемы с правами на файлы. Вам нужно дать права на файл для пользователя или группы пользователей, под которым у вас запущен веб-сервер (Apache).

Узнать пользователя можно в конфигах, например так `cat /etc/apache2/httpd.conf` или так `cat cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Там возможно будет через переменные окружения заданы значения, тогда смотрим тут `cat /etc/apache2/envvars`, ну или как у вас все настроено.

Если через конфиги не получается узнать, то можно попробовать выполнить команду `apachectl -S` или открыть php файл, в который добавить команду `echo exec('whoami');`.

Далее, смотрим какой там юзер (обычно `www-data` или `www`) и даем ему права на нужные файлы или директории. Например на всю веб директорию проекта:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /media/sf_www/laravel-test/public/
chmod -R 755 /media/sf_www/laravel-test/public/
```

Мануал по командам можно посмотреть выполнив `man chown` и `man chmod`. Либо найти в гугл например такой сайт – https://linux-faq.ru/page/komanda-chown

Если это среда для разработки и не является продакшн версией сервера и совсем ничего не работает, то можно попробовать на свой страх и риск временно поставить полные права на всю паблик директорию, но я не рекомендую это делать, только от безысходности

```
chmod -R 777 /media/sf_www/laravel-test/public/
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но проблема оказалась в другом, я дал ответ ниже

Answer (score 0):

Я понял в чем проблема, я не оговорил, что пользуюсь сервером на виртуалке, то есть обращение у меня идет как 192.168.0.249/laravel-test/somelink

где 192.168.0.249 - ip виртуалки

нужно в фаил .htaccess добавить строчку:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /laravel-test

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```